# Paypal Recurring Payments/Subscriptions

Tags: paypal, subscription, recurring

I want to integrate paypal into my website for uber type payments, Ex : Get the initial payment and on demand capture recurring payments without customer involvement what API should i use for the requirement. My paypal business account is registered to Singapore.

Answer (score 1):

In PayPal this is called reference transactions with billing agreements or future payments or vaulting, not recurring payments. Recurring payments operate on a schedule, not on demand.

The owner of the live account should contact PayPal's general business support (not technical support) to request the reference transaction/billing agreement feature. Once approved, PayPal can give you guidance on which API to integrate.

Comment: It says payapal reference transaction is deprecated, 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/ec-set-up-reference-transactions/

Comment: That API is deprecated